# Remove Radio Button List radio button in Content Place Holder

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, ajax

This is workable at normal webpage with body form tag but it cannot get the elements by name when i apply this in a master page content place holder. Can anyone help me out. Thanks a lot.

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        hideRadioSymbol();  
    });

    function hideRadioSymbol() {
        var rads = new Array();
        var rads1 = new Array();
        rads = document.getElementsByName('RadioButtonList1'); //Whatever ID u have given to ur radiolist.
        rads1 = document.getElementsByName('RadioButtonList2');

        for (var i = 0; i < rads.length; i++)
            document.getElementById(rads.item(i).id).style.display = 'none'; //hide
        for (var i = 0; i < rads1.length; i++)
            document.getElementById(rads1.item(i).id).style.display = 'none'; //hide
    }

</script>


        <input type="button" data-name="hide" value="Toggle" id="toggle2" class="btnMenu blueMenu"/>
        <div id="sidebar2">
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server"  CssClass="ph-buttonMenu ph-btn-greyMenu"  >
                    <asp:listitem>s1</asp:listitem>
                    <asp:listitem>s2</asp:listitem>
                    <asp:listitem>s3</asp:listitem>
                    <asp:listitem>s4</asp:listitem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
                   </div>
        <br />
        <input type="button" data-name="hide" value="Toggle" id="toggle3"  class="btnMenu blueMenu"/>
        <div id="sidebar3">
            <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList2" runat="server" CssClass="ph-buttonMenu ph-btn-greyMenu"  >
                    <asp:listitem>s1</asp:listitem>
                    <asp:listitem>s2</asp:listitem>
                    <asp:listitem>s3</asp:listitem>
                    <asp:listitem>s4</asp:listitem>
            </asp:RadioButtonList>
        </div>


</asp:Content>
```

Comment: You have specified id to radiobuttonlist and not name.

Answer (score -1):

<del>use this `ClientID` as follows and get the `ID` of the control instead of `Name`.


rads = document.getElementsById('<%= RadioButtonList1.ClientID %>')

rads1 = document.getElementsById('<%= RadioButtonList2.ClientID %>');</del>

You can hide the container instead of individual element. as if you have to hide `RadioButtonList1` then hide the `div` with ID `sidebar2` as follows

```
$("#sidebar2").hide()
```

as you are using jquery.

Comment: Why to use ClientId when id ClientIDMode="Static"?

Comment: @Amit I agree with you I don't consider that. But the `Name` will not be static event if you use `ClientIDMode="Static"`.  AS he is using  `getElementsByName`

Comment: Still getelementbyid should use static id in your code.

Comment: I want to hide the radio button circle to make it like a button may i know how to did it ??